# Вопрос по компоненту cxVerticalGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

В `cxVerticalGrid` добавлен `MultiEditorRow`, который состоит из 3 editors, один из которых представлен как `Combobox`.
Как узнать `Itemindex` выбранной строки в `Combobox`???

Comment: `Combobox.Itemindex` не?

Comment: нет нужно добраться до Itemindex  через cxVerticalGrid пример cxVerticalGrid1MultiEditorRow1.Properties.Editors.Items[0].EditProperties.Itemindex. Мне хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это?

Comment: Какого типа `Items[0]` и `EditProperties`? Например так: `(cxVerticalGrid1MultiEditorRow1.Properties.Editors.Items[0].EditProperties as TComboBox).ItemIndex`

Comment: в EditProperties  тип ComboBox, но ваш вариант не подходит